# IoT lifecycle events handling

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

What is the best practice to check if AWS IoT Core thing is still offline?

Being able to query the state of an AWS IoT thing will for many be an essential part of their application. Lucky AWS has a best practise on how to get lifecycle events here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

It says that we should check if device is still offline, before performing any actions.

I'm handling it on nodeJs server (listening to events), so the question is, what's the best way to handle it?

For now the plan is, to create some storage (redis?), and implement some timeout(5-10 sec), if I received disconnect event, I'll put it in DB, wait timeout, and if no other messages regarding this device will come (Connected), I'll do some logic.
Is this right approach?
The point is, not to use SQS from aws.
And as AWS docs says, the order of messages is not guaranteed, so what's the best practise to handle it?)

Answer (score 0):

If your device emits a signal at every periodic intervals, then you can treat that as a heartbeat signal.
You can maintain a timer (x minutes/hours etc) and wait for the heartbeat signal from the device.
If the timer times out and you have not received the hearbeat signal, then it is safe to assume that the device has gone offline. Such events are easy to model as a detector model in the IoT Events.

This [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iotevents/latest/developerguide/iotevents-examples-dhb.html) from AWS IoT Events is doing exactly the same thing.